# Must control characters be escaped in JSON strings?

Tags: json

The [JSON encoding standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) let assume that a string may contain control characters (e.g. '\n').

Is this assumption correct ?

Do I have to escape control characters in a JSON string ? For instance, should the byte 0x0A be replaced by "\n" ?